# jinja2 template for ansible controlled from vars

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to make things as easy as possible when adding new stuff to our configuration files in automation and I would like to generate it dynamically from the vars file, without having to adjust the template every time a new line is needed.

We use ruby, so YAML formal configuration. I was thinking about having something like this:

```
{% for variable,value in example.iteritems() %}
  {{ variable|lower() }}: "{{ value }}"
{% endfor %}
```

and in the vars file have something like:

```
example:
  host: whatever
  pass: 123
  port: 577
  and so on
```

This works without any problems, except when I need to add another indentation layer.

```
example:
  host: whatever
  pass: 123
  port: 577
  domain:
    somevalue: bla.com
    othervalue: foo.com
```

Instead of generating the same structure in the config it will generate something like:

```
domain: "{u'somevalue': u'bla.com', u'othervalue': u'foo.com'}"
```

Any way to keep the same structure and content like in the vars file ?

Thanks.

Comment: also tried by just adding: {{ example | to_nice_yaml }} but that will result in printing the "domain" part first, indenting correctly but the rest with no indentation. If I add (indent=2, true) it will indent everything correctly except the children from domain, which will have 4 spaces instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Input data:

```
vars:
  example:
    host: whatever
    pass: 123
    port: 577
    domain:
      somevalue: bla.com
      othervalue: foo.com
```

4 spaces yaml template.j2:

```
example:{{ example | to_nice_yaml | comment(decoration='    ') }}
```

Result:

```
example:
    domain:
        othervalue: foo.com
        somevalue: bla.com
    host: whatever
    pass: 123
    port: 577
```

2 spaces yaml template.j2:

```
example:{{ example | to_yaml(indent=2, default_flow_style=False) | comment(decoration='  ') }}
```

Result:

```
example:
  domain:
    othervalue: foo.com
    somevalue: bla.com
  host: whatever
  pass: 123
  port: 577
```

Note that ouput order of dict keys may differ from your input, but you shouldn't rely on it anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately no, same issue with all methods: Will add 2 spaces correctly everywhere except for the domain children, it will add 4 there and will result in a invalid yaml file.

Comment: @SeerKan I've updated the answer with samples. Please inform what is wrong with it.

Comment: sorry, I've been away. Will try to test your change this week and if it works will select your answer as the correct one. Thank you.